# How are callbacks fired here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question,

How can I call this as a simple and basic function instead of a `window.resize` event?

```
$( window ).resize( debouncer( function ( e ) {
    // do stuff 
    $('body').append('<p>done</p>');
} ) );
```

On window resizing I append a `<p>` element - However the debouncer function below, seems to be called first which debounces the window-resizing.

The question is much simpler than that, how do I call the debouncer as a function instead of calling it on window.resize? Does this has something to do with callbacks?

E.g I want to call a function in my code instead of on window-resize.

I figured I could remove , `$( window ).resize`  and replace it with a function, e.g `var greet = function` and then call `greet()` to no avail.

*This seems really basic but I don't get how functions are called between the `debouncer`, how it is called and how the debounced-code gets called.*

---

The debouncer function that gets called on window.resize

(*should be irrelevant, but I include it anyway*):

```
function debouncer( func , timeout ) {
   var timeoutID , slice = Array.prototype.slice , timeout = timeout || 200;
   return function () {
      var scope = this , args = arguments;
      clearTimeout( timeoutID );
      timeoutID = setTimeout( function () {
          func.apply( scope , slice.call( args ) );
      } , timeout );
   }
}
```

Comment: `debouncer()` returns a "debounced" function built from the one you passed. You could just store that function and call it later.

Comment: I've written a function called debounced() which is called like this. debouncer(debounced(),3000). Is this the correct way to call debounced() actually debounced? What do I pass as parameter? The function name?

Comment: Yes, the function name, without the "call operator" parentheses, of course. Otherwise you'd be calling it and passing the value it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your debouncer function returns function. I think what you are trying to achieve, is call that function from code. If that is the case you can do as following:

```
var timeout = 100;
function debouncer_func( e ) {
    // do stuff 
    $('body').append('<p>done</p>');
}
debouncer(debouncer_func, timeout)();
```

You can also do this as below:

```
debouncer(function(e){
  // do stuff 
  $('body').append('<p>done</p>');
}, 100)();
```

Basically here your debouncer function is returning a function. So `debouncer(args)()` will call your returned function from debouncer.